# How do I test mandrill api with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec, devise, mandrill

So my client has reported that many of the emails are going to the wrong person, and I would like to write some feature tests to find and make sure that they are receiving the email and what it says in my specs. 
I have mandrill_mailer which uses mandril api, and before it sends out I would like to see what the message is.

For example. Create a new user account -> creates the user, and then sends out a welcome email. in devise it calls RegistrationMailer.new_registration(resource).deliver
which then sends a email to the user:

```
  def new_registration(user)
user = User.find_by_email(user["email"])
mandrill_mail template: 'new-registration',
subject: 'Welcome to ContentBlvd!',
to: { email: user["email"], name: user["full_name"] },
vars: {
  'first_name' =>   user["full_name"],
  'unsubscribe' =>  "#{CONFIG[:protocol]}#{CONFIG[:host]}/unsubscribe?email=#{user.email}"
}
```

end

In my mailer how do I test this mail object?
I tried ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, but it returns nil (Since I'm using mandrill mailer...) 
So I tried - MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer.message
But no luck.... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

At this point, MandrillMailer appears to support a [robust offline testing](https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer#offline-testing) set of options.  In particular, `MandrillMailer.deliveries` can now be examined for expectations or debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As per [wiki](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-ruby/wiki/Home) you need to mock [Excon](https://github.com/geemus/excon)

```ruby
# spec/rails_helper.rb

config.before(:all) do 
  Excon.defaults[:mock] = true
  Excon.stub({}, {body: "{\"html\":\"RESULT\"}", status: 200})
end
```

Answer (score -4):

You don't have to use the Mandrill gem to send emails using Mandrill. Just use the Rails default Mailer and add the configuration to application.rb or production.rb to use your Mandrill's account.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.